# Nokia C01 Plus - is there a way to disable the "Emergency Number"

Tags: contacts, phone-app, android-go, emergency-calls, nokia

I have a Nokia C01 Plus running Android version 11 - this is Android Go.

For some reason, it pocket dials the number which is shown as "Emergency Number"

> [image]

This is not something I stored, but it came with the phone. It's not editable. Or deletable. It's also not part of the "Emergency Information" stored in "Settings -> About Phone".

That is blank in my case

[image]

---

So I want to disable/delete/edit the "Emergency Call" number. Is there a way to do this? I know about Call Confirm apps, but I don't want to use it because that would enable "Confirm" for every number - which I don't want. I don't pocket-dial any number except this one. And it happens 5 times a day.

Comment: [Multiple presses of power button seem to trigger it](https://community.phones.nokia.com/discussion/65939/pocket-calls-to-emergency-number-solved) //Also explains how to disable

Comment: @beeshyams I think you are right but my phone doesn't have any way of turning it off - I don't have an "Emergency & Safety" option in settings at all

Comment: Well, I would think of putting the phone in a different pocket /position /or with a folding screen protector to avoid accidental press

Comment: Does the Android Settings have a built-in search? If so, anything returned when searching for "emergency"?

Comment: @AndrewT. only the emergency Information setting for which I have given the screenshot